# What is the difference between the "Main Index Template"(index.php) and HomePage(front-page.php)

Tags: template-hierarchy

Just wonder what is the difference between the "Main Index Template" `index.php` and HomePage `front-page.php`.
It seems that `front-page.php` is displayed when visiting `https://www.example.com/`, but `index.php` seems also to be served for such a purpose.
If `index.php` is not used when visiting `https://www.example.com`, when it will be used?

Comment: Have you referred to the template hierarchy? https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I read the document. If I understand correct, index.php works more like a fallback template, if for all cases, there are other templates available, then it will never be used?

Comment: @alancc you just answered your own question in a comment. front-page.php will be served first, if it does not exist (nor any others in the chain), index.php will be served as fallback. And yes, if front-page.php exists, index.php will not be served.

Comment: @Lovor, THank you very much.

Comment: @alancc Feel free to answer your own question here, so future visitors will see it better

Comment: @alancc It's usually not necessary to have _every_ other template, so you'll usually have something that's using index.php. I believe it's also a requirement of themes on wordpress.org.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, Thank you very much.